# Skip `n` iterations in foreach loop

Tags: c#, xml, foreach

How to skip `n` number of iterations in the for each loop.

Below is an example. In the if condition there will be more then 1 node involved. These nodes should be omitted from the foreach loop. E.g. in the if statement 3 nodes are involved I need the foreach loop to jump to the 4th node on it' next iteration.

```
foreach (XmlNode node in docs.SelectNodes(query))
{
   if (condition = true)
    {

       do
        {

           XmlNode nextnode = parentnode.NextSibling;
           string nextnodetest = nextnode.LocalName;
           if (nextnodetest = "Programme")
           {
            //calculate duration.
            }
       while (nextnodetest !=programme)

      }
    // skip the nodes in the foreach loop that were involved in the if/do statements above
}
```

How do I skip these nodes from the foreach loop iteration.

Comment: Use `continue;` when the condition is satisfied.

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking, what does this mean *" During the first loop check condition and do some job on the next nodes*" also Please clarify this *"Now the nodes that were included in the if statement should be omitted from the foreach loop*"

Comment: Yes the nodes that were included in the if statement should be excluded from the foreach loop, so continue simple will not work.

Comment: Ok so everyone is sufficiently confused, You will need to rewrite your question to be more concise, maybe a better example. If English is your problem, maybe you can get someone to help you out with the wording

Comment: Changed, is it better now.

Comment: You can use for loop and for each item that satisfied in condition add one number to counter of loop

Comment: @SaeedBolhasani: what you are saying looks good, can you show an example for this

Comment: This question would be a million times better if the code were as real as possible. As close to a [mcve] you can get.

Comment: @user726720 - Are the nodes to be skipped always linear?

Comment: @Enigmativity: Please see my updated question. It gives more code and a better understanding

Comment: @Enigmativity: No they are not always linear. If 4 nodes were involved in the if statement I want to skip 4 nodes. If 3 were involved I want to skip 3 nodes. So it all depends on the `IF` condition

Comment: @user726720 - Yes, but that's not what I'm asking. `docs.SelectNodes(query)` returns a linear list of nodes. Are you always skipping nodes in the same sequence returned by the query? Or does it jump around?

Comment: Let me be clear here with an example. Lets say in the foreach loop      node =10. Then we enter if statement (1st iteration). it works on 2 nodes. THese nodes should be skipped from foreach loop in the next iteration. So in the next iteration for the if statement works on 3 nodes, now these 3 nodes should be skipped from the next iteration. So in conclustion `docs.SelectNodes(query)` returns a linear list but the skipping inside the if statement is not linear depends on the if statement condition

Comment: @user726720 - You are not any clearer. Let me ask it this way. If the `if` statement works on `3` nodes then the **next** three nodes are skipped? Is that right? If so, then the `if` statement is moving to the next node `3` times?

Comment: @Enigmativity: yes that's correct if the `if` statements works on 3 nodes, and the `do/while` loop ends so foreach loop in the next iteration will skip these 3 nodes

Comment: @user726720 - You're not following me. I want to know if the `if` statement works on 3 nodes are those the nodes that the `foreach` loop would have continued with had the `if` only worked on one node? Are they processed in exactly the same sequence if they were processed in the `if` as they would have been in the `foreach` loop?

Comment: The 3 nodes the if statement works on should be skipped by the foreach loop. Check `DisplayNames` answer below. That's what I require

Comment: @user726720 - You're still not answering my question. Please re-read my previous comment.

Comment: @Enigmativity: If statement works on 3 nodes are those nodes that the foreach loop will drop. If can work will multiple nodes depends on the condition. Yes the sequence is same.

Comment: @user726720 - "Yes the sequence is same" - that's what I've been wanting to hear. That's the important part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe something like this

```
        XmlNodeList nodeList = docs.SelectNodes(query)
        XmlNode node;
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.Count; i++)
        {
            node = nodeList[i];
            if (condition == true)
            {

                int itemsToSkip = 0;
                string nextnodetest;
                do
                {
                   ...

                    if (nextnodetest == "Programme")
                    {
                        itemsToSkip++;
                        //calculate duration.
                    }
                } while (nextnodetest != "Programme");

                i = i + itemsToSkip;
            }

            ... your code 
        }
```

Comment: There is a small issue in your code. It's doing an `i=i+itemsToSkip` but then when it goes to the foreach loop it does an i++ again. So it add another 1.

Comment: then just subtract 1... `i = i + itemsToSkip - 1;`

Comment: Sorry, just ignore. It's doing it properly. Let me dig more into it. Thanks.

Comment: Yes it did im away from work wil accepy tomorrow morning

Comment: Fine. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
var nodes = docs.SelectNodes(query).OfType<XmlNode>().ToArray();
for (int i=0; i< nodes.Length; i++)
{
    if(condition....)
    {
      ....
      i+= n;
    }

}
```

Comment: it says `System.Xml.XmlNodeList` does not contain a definition for 'Count'

Comment: `System.Xml.XmlNodeList` does not contain a definition for 'toArray'

Comment: @user726720 - You need to do `docs.SelectNodes(query).OfType<XmlNode>().ToArray()` for this to work.

Comment: @Enigmativity&@Saeed: this seems to satisfy my needs of what I want to achieve. I will just go through the rest of the code now and see if this works fine. But for now it's excellent. @Saeed, kindly please update the answer and I will accept this shortly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use a for loop :

```
var nodes = docs.SelectNodes(query).ToList();
for(int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i += n)
{
   XmlNode node = nodes[i];
}
```